# How to pass a long as a offset in stream.read?

Tags: c#, stream

```
long bytesread = 0;
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(ficheiroaEnviar); 
tamanhoFicheiroEnviar = f.Length;
byte[] chunkFicheiro; 
while (!tudoFeito)
{
    long oQueFalta = (tamanhoFicheiroEnviar - bytesread);

    if (oQueFalta < tamanhoChunkPredefenido)
    {
        chunkFicheiro = new byte[tamanhoChunkPredefenido];
    }
    else
    {
        chunkFicheiro = new byte[oQueFalta];
    }

    using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(ficheiroaEnviar, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        lock (fsSource)
        {
            fsSource.Seek(bytesread, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fsSource.Read(chunkFicheiro, bytesread, chunkFicheiro.Length);
        }
    }
    bytesread += chunkFicheiro.Length;
}
```

I want to be able to read a 10GB file piece by piece? 
The max number of an integer is 2,147,483,647 and 10 GB has 10 000 000 000 bytes. How can i use a offset stream.read(other,**int offset**,other) so that it can work with large files?

(edit question or title if you desire)

Comment: The first parameter of [FileStream.Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) is an Int64. Your code should work (at least for everything related to the Seek call)

Comment: I am talking about `fsSource.Read(chunkFicheiro, bytesread, chunkFicheiro.Length);` The bytesread, if i am using a 10 GB file needs to be larger then an **int**

Comment: @meme That's the offset to use in the _destination_ array, not the source stream.  Since an array can't be larger than `int,MaxValue` there's no point of allowing an offset larger than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offset value in the read operation is the offset in the target array for the read operation.  When reading from a fileStream, the position will increase as you read. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

> offset
> Type: System.Int32
> **The byte offset in array at which the read bytes will be placed.**

Your seek operation will progress the stream (although it should not be needed)

Your read should use 0 for the offset unless you want to place it at a different index in the chunkFicheiro array

```
//Example of reading the file from the stream
do
{
    bytesRead = fsSource.Read(chunkFicheiro, 0, chunkFicheiro.Length);
    //Do something with the chunk if bytesRead > 0
} while (bytesRead > 0);
```